# Can threads be used to increase the speed of hash key matching in perl?

Tags: multithreading, perl

Can threading be used to increase the speed of hash key matching? 
I have a hash that contains the top 1 Mil alexa sites.  Matching ~100 unique hosts against the alexa hash takes far longer than I'd like it to.  What/where would be the most appropriate way/place to introduce threading to speed this thing up?

```
foreach my $host (keys %unique_hosts) {      
  if ($host =~ /(([\w\-]+)\.([\w\-]+))$/) {
    my $domain = $1;
    $in_alexa++ if /$domain$/ ~~ %alexa_sites;
  }
}
```

Edit: Mem looks ok.

```
PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND 
7533 user      20   0  457m 339m 1676 R 99.0 34.2   0:15.31 bind.pl
```

Comment: With a hash that size, are you sure you're not having issues with your memory being swapped out to disk?  If so, no amount of threading is going to speed up your disk I/O.

Comment: At a million records, it begins to look like a database with LIKE queries would work better.

Comment: This is really the point where you want a database, not a hash. Might I suggest [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/downloads)? :)

Comment: Do you really want to do `$in_alexa` if the host is `def.com` and `abcdef.com` is a key of `%alexa_sites`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For each host, you are doing one million regex matches. That's why it's slow.

Yes, threads could help by using otherwise unused CPU cores. But that's not the right solution.

I'm assuming you're trying to check if `$host` is a key of `%alexa_sites` or a subdomain of a key in `%alexa_sites`.

```
for my $host (keys %unique_hosts) {      
    while (1) {
        if (exists($alexa_sites{$host})) {
           ++$in_alexa;
           last;
        }

        $host =~ s/^[^.]*\.//
           or last;
    }
}
```

Now you're doing ~300 fast hash lookups instead of 100,000,000 slow regex matches.